# Delegate new coins to existing wallet

Tags: baker

I have delegated coins in my wallet. When I send new coins to the wallet do I have to delegate those coins to the baker or do they automatically get delegated?

Answer (score 2):

Automatically delegated. New coins must still wait the normal waiting period before they are visible to the baker.